# Complex Analysis - Determine ALL functions such that ...

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $\alpha$ be a real number and $C$ a positive number. Determine all entire functions $f$ such that
$$|f(z)|\le C(1+|z|)^\alpha \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$

I don't recall seeing anything like this throughout our entire course, and my textbook is completely devoid of something that looks like this. So I'm at a total loss.

I imagine it may include polynomials, since we'd need to have:
$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{(1+|z|)^\alpha}\right|<C$$
so for any particular polynomial, $p(x)=a_0+...+a_nz^n$ we can choose $\alpha>n$, But I'm not sure about how to determine ALL entire functions.

Comment: Hint: Entire functions have power series.

Comment: So ... if I can show that a power series fits the criteria, then ALL entire functions do. correct?

Comment: You may write $f$ as its power series representation, and then see what restrictions your hypotheses then impose on $f$.

Comment: It seems to me that a power series, having infinite powers, destroys $\alpha$, or blows up $C$.

Comment: Power series with finitely many nonzero coefficients are still power series.

Comment: Are you familiar with Cauchy's inequality for the coefficients of a Taylor series (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)? What does that tell you if $n > \alpha$?